# Show that $\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p} \geq \log{\log{x}}-\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I should be able to do this using elementary methods only but the proof is evading me. Similar proofs I've seen rely on showing the Riemann Zeta product form diverges for s=1.

Comment: Imagine you're Euler and look at $$\prod_{p \leqslant x} \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p}\biggr)^{-1} \geqslant \sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{1}{n}$$ for a while. A strategy might raise its head.

Comment: got it! embarrassingly this is written on the page I've been staring at...